# Query to copy data of multiple columns from one table to another in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

I want to copy data of multiple columns (latitude, longitude, hotel_name) from table "hotel" and paste it to another table "marker"'s columns (latitude, longitude, name). I have tried to implement it by using the query below:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO marker (latitude, longitude, name) SELECT latitude, longitude, hotel_name FROM hotel WHERE hotel_name= ".$value." ;";
$ret = $db->query($sql);
```

After running this query I am getting an error saying the statement below:

```
SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, near &quot;westin&quot;: syntax error
```

Please guide me where have I gone wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would guess it should be hotel_name= '".$value."' .You would probably need single quotes around a text value

Comment: As Simon said. But I think it should be `hotel_name= '".$value."'`. The single quote inside double quoted string